# Force delete Git branch from remote

Tags: git

I was working on some proof-of-concept code and had created a branch for it. Since it took close to 2 weeks, i was also pushing it to the remote on a daily basis.

The POC is now done and I do not want to merge it.
I was able to delete the local branch with
`git branch -D <branchname>`

But when i try to push it fails with the merge error (Branches cannot be deleted until merged).
Is there a way to delete unmerged branches remotely?

Comment: What hosting platform are you using on the remote side?  GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, something else?

Comment: It is Stash/Bitbucket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @inigo not really. I think what CodeWizard has mentioned looks like the likely issue here. I am checking with my Git admins if they have the restriction set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to delete unmerged branches remotely?

```
git push :origin/branch

# or
git push origin --delete branch
```

According to your comments, you cant do it on bitbucket, the reason can be since your administrator blocked the option to delete branches

**Prevert Deletion** in the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: This gives the error that Branches that have not been merged cannot be deleted

Comment: This is the way to do it, so if it doesn't work, then the answer is “no,” and you'll have to figure out why Bitbucket is not letting you delete the branch.  Contact your server administrator.

Comment: If you cant your administrator blocked it with restrictions

Answer (score 2):

In Git, local and remote branches are separate objects. Deleting a local branch doesn’t remove the remote branch.

To delete a remote branch, use the git push command with the -d (--delete) option:

`git push remote_name --delete branch_name`

Where remote_name is usually origin:

```
Output:
...
 - [deleted]         branch_name
```

There is also an alternative command to delete a remote branch, that is, at least for me harder to remember:

`git push origin remote_name :branch_name`